# Laravel Query Failing in Production

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel Project, I have written a query to return  the store under 10KM based On users Input
the query is

```
return Store::select('id', DB::raw(sprintf(
        '(6371 * acos(cos(radians(%1$.7f)) * cos(radians(`lat`)) * cos(radians(`lon`) - radians(%2$.7f)) + sin(radians(%1$.7f)) * sin(radians(`lat`)))) AS distance',
                    $request->lat,
                    $request->lon
             )))
            ->having('distance', '<', 10)
            ->where('id', $request->store_id)
            ->first();
```

my stores table includes `lat` and `lon`  columns as well..

user request is

```
 {
    "address_line_1":"line 1",
    "lat":"8.8621838999999998",
    "lon":"76.723247799999996",
    "store_id":2
}
```

**The Fun fact is that this code is working fine in my local machine(returns stores object)but not in production even if there is a store within 10Km**

Please anyone can find what's wrong with this query??

thanks in advance

Comment: if you do `->toSql()` instead of `first()` and then dump the SQL query and run it directly on the server (i.e. using a client of sorts) do you get results?

Comment: No... i didnt got any results

Comment: @JEJ do you get results doing what @apokryfos said but in your local machine where the normal query is working ? If the answer is `yes`, and you are using the same database engine and version as your local machine, then I am pretty sure you have no data matching that criteria...

Comment: This is more of an issue with the query rather than laravel/eloquent. I would recommend you provide an example row of data and an example input for which you get data locally but not on prod. Also share details like table structure as well as db version and storage engine used. If any of these differs between local and production then do mention that as well